# Migrating from Sql Server 2000 to Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, migration

There's a machine running `Win7`; `SQL Server 2000`. (Suppose) Remote connections to the machine aren't possible. I need to copy a database from the machine to other one which is running `SQL Server 2008 R2/2005`;

How would I do that?

Comment: Which protocols/ports are allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Backup/restore will help
- If you have physical administrative access to the server - shut it down, copy DB files and attach

Comment: So there are no addtional upgrade-conversions between versions am I right?

Comment: You may wamt to change the compatibility level of DB from 80 to 100. Thats all